# Derivative of function with respect to $x$ where $x$ is the order of a derivative of another function.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

When I learn math I always have lot of thoughts and ideas in my head and some of them are weird. But I came aross a question, which is... also kind of weird.

How can a problem like this be solved? Is it possible?

$$\frac{d}{dx}\Bigg(\frac{d^x}{dw^x}w^2\Bigg)$$

Comment: I don't think this is possible by any stretch of the imagination. To differentiate with respect to $x$ , which I reiterate is a **positive integer**, you have to **define** differentiation on the natural numbers, which is a discrete space where limits would not have the same definition.

Comment: $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}$ means "take derivative $n$ times", so...

Comment: Well, derivative is an operation. For example, multiplication is an operation too. If you apply multiplication iteratively, you get an exponential function. So we turned an operation into a function by iterating it. So can't we do the same for derivative, since it is an operation too?

Comment: Multiplication is not "iterative", at least using any standard definition of multiplication for real numbers. Also, don't confuse the terms: operation and function are almost the same thing (an operation is a function from a power of a set $X$, to itself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for it to even make sense to talk about $\dfrac{d}{dx}$ in this context, $x$ must be able to represent any real number, not just integers.  This leads us to [fractional derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus).

[Here is a paper](http://web.ist.utl.pt/duarte.valerio/FSS2009I.pdf) on variable-order fractional derivatives.  After skimming the paper I would say the answer to your second question is yes, although it looks rather messy.

Comment: It indeed does look VERY messy. I'll still wait some time before accepting your answer.